# Am I misunderstanding something about Array Lists?

Tags: java

Write a new method named `toArrayList()` that returns an `ArrayList<E> object` containing all elements in 
the calling list, in the same order (i.e., the head node’s data should be stored in index 0 of the returned array list).

Thats one of the questions we have. I wrote a loop that should take the elements in the calling list and put them in a new Array, but I when I want to return `ArrayList<E>`, i get an error saying, "cannot find symbol - class `ArrayList`."

I could write an `ArrayList` class but our teacher always walks us through it step by step in the homework. If there is a certain class or method we have to write to complete the homework he tells us so. So I feel like I am missing something here because there is no where in the assignment that tells us to write an `ArrayList class`.

Comment: You are probably missing a `import` statement.

Comment: Could you add the piece of code...

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList

Comment: up voted as i hate to see a new user losing out. but do read the [FAQ] learn to use google, the starters chat and search earlier questions and then post a new one.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16189/hello-world this room will help hope new comers are allowed in?!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the class `java.util.ArrayList`. Take a look at the doc. You can put `elements` to it directly without using a `primitive` array.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to explain things better in code.

We are just taking a given list and copying it in these examples. The important methods are the copy functions at the bottom of the class.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListUtil{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ints.add(1);
        ints.add(2);
        ints.add(3);

        List<Integer> copyOfInts = copy(Integer.class, ints);
        System.out.println("The value of the first element in both lists is 1: " + copyOfInts.get(0) == ints.get(1));
        System.out.println("The two lists are not the same: " + ints == copyOfInts);
        ints.remove(0);
        System.out.println("The first ints has 2 elements : " + ints.size() == 2);
        System.out.println("The first copys have 3: " + coyOfInts.size() == 3);

        String[] strings = {"String 1", "String 2", "String 3"};
        List<String> copyOfStrings = copy(String.class, strings);
        System.out.println("The second element of the copy is \"String 2\": " + "String 2".equals(strings.get(0));
    }

    /**
     * I create copies of arrays of type
     * @Param Class<T> typeOfT - the type that the list of T represents. This is useful to tell teh compiler what type the list really is at runtime.
     * @Param T[] the array you want to copy
     * @Return List<T> the copied list
     */

    public static final <T> List<T> copy(Class<T> typeOfT, T[] arrayToCopy){
        List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayToCopy.length(); i++){
            newList.add(arrayToCopy[i]);
        }

        return newList;

    }

    /**
     * I create copies of lists of type
     * I am also what is called a paramaterized method. I am type safe, but can work on many different types.
     * @Param Class<T> typeOfT - the type that the list of T represents. This is useful to tell teh compiler what type the list really is at runtime.
     * @Param List<T> the list you want to copy
     * @Return List<T> the copied list
     */

      public static final <T> List<T> copy(Class<T> typeOfT, List<T> listToCopy){
        List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
        newList.addAll(listToCopy);
        return newList;
    }   
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html